# Why is static analyzer complaining "Potential leak of an object"

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I am running in non-ARC mode. I get a warning from static analyzer saying "Potential leak of an object" in the line where I initialize myObj. I don't see this warning if I compile in ARC mode though. Any idea what's going wrong here?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface MyClass : NSObject
-(instancetype) initWithData:(NSData *)data error:(NSError **)error;
@end
@implementation MyClass
-(instancetype) initWithData:(NSData *)data error:(NSError **)error
{
    if (data == nil)
    {
        if (error != NULL)
        {
            *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"MyClass" code:1 userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:@"Data is nil."}];
        }
        return nil;
    }
    self = [super init];
    return self;
}
@end
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSData *data = nil;
        MyClass *myObj = [[MyClass alloc] initWithData:data error:&error];
        NSLog(@"myObj: %@", myObj);
        [myObj release];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to release `self` before returning nil from an initializer.

Comment: Thanks @Darren. That makes sense. The only issue is that self is alloc'd outside the "init" method, would it be appropriate as per convention to release it here?